# cd: too many arguments - spaces properly escaped + quoted?

Tags: cygwin

Using cygwin terminal, I have the following in my .bashrc:

```
export WINHOME="/cygdrive/c/Users/userName"
export TUTORING="$WINHOME/Desktop/Coding\ Projects/Tutoring/"
```

When I open cygwin, here's what happens:

```
$ cd $TUTORING
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

So then I tried:

```
$ echo $TUTORING
/cygdrive/c/Users/userName/Desktop/Coding\ Projects/Tutoring
```

Copy pasting the output from echo:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/userName/Desktop/Coding\ Projects/Tutoring
```

And this seems to work. Any idea why cd has a problem with my variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word splitting happens after variable expansion. From `man bash`:

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution,  and  arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators.

The correct way is to use double quotes:

```
export TUTORING="$WINHOME/Desktop/Coding Projects/Tutoring/"
cd "$TUTORING"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes for escape the whole path.

Because space inside path, cd command thinks there are several parameters