# How to set JAVA_HOME from the ubuntu shell on WSL2?

Tags: java, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I installed WSL2 on my Windows 10 Home. I want to use Maven (which I verified is installed correctly on Windows).

In an ubuntu shell from Windows Terminal, I set JAVA_HOME in my `.profile` but it would not get set.
I ran these commands to try out the correct way to set JAVA_HOME but they do not work.

```
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user$ mvn
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user$ JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: too many arguments

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user$ cd /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ mvn --version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/'Program\ Files'/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: too many arguments

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/'Program\ Files'/Java/jdk-11.0.10
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: too many arguments

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ cd /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ pwd
/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin

user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$


user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10"
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: too many arguments

user@DESKTOP:~$ export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10"
user@DESKTOP:~$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed user Aran's (unfortunately deleted) answer below - I edited /etc/environment and added

```
export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10"
```

then in `.bashrc` I added

```
source /etc/environment
```

and thought it worked because when I did an `env` in the ubuntu shell, I saw JAVA_HOME

I installed mvn and it still gives the same error:

```
$ mvn The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I think it is the space in "Program Files".
I do have JDK 11 installed. Verified by navigating to JAVA_HOME/bin and I can see javac.exe.

**So the issue is not fixed.**

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what the Maven script tries to do with JAVA_HOME, which may help find the correct workaround :

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
  JAVACMD=`which java`
else
  JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" >&2
  echo "This environment variable is needed to run this program" >&2
  echo "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Please note that the script goes through the "else" part, and that the "! -x" part is where it fails.

---

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893108/cd-too-many-arguments-spaces-properly-escaped-quoted).
I do not have access to how Maven is accessing JAVA_HOME.
The question is not about `cd $JAVA_HOME`. It is about using `mvn` Maven. If Maven is using `$JAVA_HOME` internally, there is no way I can see how to make it use `"$JAVA_HOME"`

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10"`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it does not work. I updated my question to show the result when I executed your command.

Comment: I would recommend you to install java and maven on WSL.

Comment: @dan1st No, that would be installing it twice. That is not a good thing.

Comment: Instead of `cd $JAVA_HOME`, you might want to use `cd "$JAVA_HOME"`. Also, you might want to set the windows java path in `JAVA_HOME` if you want to use the windows maven installation.

Comment: I didn't tell you to cd to the JAVA_HOME folder. it has a space in it. So you must quote it.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+bash+cd+variable%2C+too+many+arguments) of [cd: too many arguments - spaces properly escaped + quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54893108/4642212). `cd $JAVA_HOME` expands to `cd /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10`, which is not what you want. Use proper quoting: `cd "${JAVA_HOME}"` or `cd "$JAVA_HOME"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon This is not a duplicate of that question. Please read my question carefully. I do not have access to how Maven is accessing JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please understand that the question is not about `cd $JAVA_HOME`. It is about using `mvn` Maven. If Maven is using $JAVA_HOME internally, there is no way I can see how to make it use `"$JAVA_HOME"`

Comment: `mvn` is a just `bat` and `shell` file respectively. You can certainly edit that script, but it wasn't intended to mix and match between Windows and Linux. So the real question is what are you trying to do? Why do you want to run maven in WSL? Perhaps you should dockerize it and be done with it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch trying to run `mvn` from the command line in a familiar bash shell rather than the Windows `cmd`.

Comment: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` and then `java -version`. If that doesn't work the rest is a pointless exercise. If it does, then you can try editing the `mvn` script. It's literally a script that executes a `java` process.

Comment: I couldn't tell you other than three people "chose" to downvote, and I am not one of them. I have worked on macs for about a decade now. When forced to work on Windows, I have given up on trying to make it behave sanely and just focus on making it behave at all. Once you start writing truly platform agnostic code it doesn't matter as much. Anyway, I suggest you install Java for ubuntu in WSL. **OR**, you could try `wsl mvn` to see if that works without it. But you're trying to hack Windows to work sanely. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround: (not an exact solution to the question)**

Set the JAVA_HOME variable from Windows, via the gui and use Windows Powershell instead of ubuntu shell.

[image: Java home]

Comment: This does not work at all. Setting it in Windows does not transfer it to WSL2

Comment: If you follow your instruction and then open a ubuntu shell, you will not see JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Although it does work from Powershell.now `mvn --version` +1 upvote

Answer (score 1):

Add copy of java.exe with the name just "java" . That will prevent mvn from complaining - it looks for "$JAVACMD"which is defined as JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing OpenJDK 17 on WSL(link below).

Run the following commands in WSL (I was using Windows Terminal)

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
3. java --version

Link: https://techviewleo.com/install-java-openjdk-on-ubuntu-linux/